# iOS Add loading text with animating period character

Tags: ios, uilabel

Not sure how to describe this, but what would be the easiest way to have a UILabel display Loading, then Loading., then Loading.., then Loading..., and then repeat?

I have been looking into timers but it all seems a bit excessive. Anyone know of a cool and quick trick to pull something like that off? Thanks!

Comment: what about using an UIActivityIndicatorView ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure about your specific use case (more info please or code?) but have you tried animation blocks? Something like:

```
- (void)animate
{
    __block UIView * blockSelf = self;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^{
        if ([blockSelf.label.text isEqualToString:@"Loading..."]) {
            blockSelf.label.text = @"Loading";
        } else {
            blockSelf.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", blockSelf.label.text];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (blockSelf.processIsFinished) {
            [self moveOn];
        } else {
            [blockSelf animate];
        }
    }];
}
```

Alternatively, something like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) might be useful depending on what type of process is "loading".